# ¿Existe alguna manera de evitar que se ingresen por teclado y copien los caracteres "e - ." en un input number de HTML5?

Tags: html5, validación, input

Tengo un input de tipo number de HTML5 y este permite el ingreso de los caracteres "e  -  ."

Existe la manera de evitar el ingreso por teclado y copiado de estos caracteres en el input number?

```html
<input type="number">
```

Comment: Necesitas ser más concreto. ¿Qué es lo que quieres conseguir exactamente? ¿Solo quieres que sean válidos números enteros positivos, o algo más? ¿Es totalmente necesario evitar que ingresen datos por teclado, si luego la validación (Suponiendo que esté hecha como quieres, y como esperas que funcione) falla?

Deberias editar la pregunta con esos detalles para que sea mejor recibida.

Comment: Lo que quiero conseguir es que el usuario no pueda ingresar estos 3 caracteres que por defecto permiten los input number. De tal manera que solo se permita el ingreso de números enteros positivos.